# How to print a number with two dots in the C language?

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, printf, double

The problem is when I run this code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    double motorcyclePrice;

    scanf("%f", &motorcyclePrice);

    printf("The motorcycle of the brand %s it's %lf.", motorcycleBrand, motorcyclePrice);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the print if I put "1.000.000" it will be "1.000000", so how can I set the output to be the same as input?  I tried it with int, float and double and still the same...

Comment: Use a string instead.

Comment: I will try it, but i want the number still being number... or there is way to convert str to int/float/double? -Thanks.

Comment: You need to set the locale to something other than C and you may need to add a quote to the conversion specification and hope you have a sufficiently POSIX-compliant standard C library.  It ain't trivial, in other words.

Comment: @JamesPhoenix *"or there is way to convert str to int/float/double?"* - Yep, look up `sscanf`

Comment: What is `1.000.000` supposed to represent? Is that the number 1? Or one million? In other words, is the `.` supposed to be a decimal point or a digit grouping?

Comment: James Phoenix, really need to know the answer to [@AndreasWenzel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70500889/how-to-print-a-number-with-two-dots-in-the-c-language#comment124626015_70500889) question.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: in a locale where `,` is used as the 'radix character' (aka 'decimal point'), the `.` is often used as the thousands grouping character.  In such a locale, `1.000.000` represents one million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my earlier [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70500889/how-to-print-a-number-with-two-dots-in-the-c-language#comment124624359_70500889), I observed that you need a lot of things working in your favour to get the result you desire.

- You need to set the locale to a locale other than the `"C"` or `"POSIX"` locale.
- Using the empty string as the locale in a call to [`setlocale()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html) means that the program should use the locale specified in the environment.
- You need a locale that sets the 'radix character' (decimal point).
- You need a locale that sets the 'grouping character'.
- You need a version of [`printf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) that recognizes the `'` format modifier.
- You also need a version of [`scanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) that permits the grouping character in the input, even though neither Standard C nor POSIX requires this.

So, the input parsing is extremely problematic — you need something other than Standard C `scanf()` to do that job.

You can generate the output if the locale is set up correctly.

Demo program:

```c
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double price;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    if (scanf("%lf", &price) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("%'.2f\n", price);
    return 0;
}
```

On a Mac running macOS Catalina (10.15.7), with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in the environment, I can enter `1234567.89` and get the output `1,234,567.89`.  It wasn't until I tried an exhaustive test of the locales in `/usr/share/locale` that I found some locales that use `,` as the decimal point and `.` as the grouping character — none of `de_DE.UTF-8`, `fr_FR.UTF-8`, `es_ES.UTF-8`, `pt_PT.UTF-8`, `it_IT.UTF-8` set the grouping character.

My test program is called `pr17`.

```sh
$ for locale in $(cd /usr/share/locale; ls -d *.UTF-8)
> do echo "$locale: $(LANG=$locale ./pr17 <<< '1234567,89')"
> done
af_ZA.UTF-8: 1.234.567,89
am_ET.UTF-8: 1,234,567.00
be_BY.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
bg_BG.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
ca_ES.UTF-8: 1234567,89
cs_CZ.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
da_DK.UTF-8: 1.234.567,89
de_AT.UTF-8: 1234567,89
de_CH.UTF-8: 1234567,89
de_DE.UTF-8: 1234567,89
el_GR.UTF-8: 1.234.567,89
en_AU.UTF-8: 1,234,567.00
en_CA.UTF-8: 1,234,567.00
en_GB.UTF-8: 1,234,567.00
en_IE.UTF-8: 1,234,567.00
en_NZ.UTF-8: 1,234,567.00
en_US.UTF-8: 1,234,567.00
es_ES.UTF-8: 1234567,89
et_EE.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
eu_ES.UTF-8: 1234567,89
fi_FI.UTF-8: 1.234.567,89
fr_BE.UTF-8: 1234567,89
fr_CA.UTF-8: 1234567,89
fr_CH.UTF-8: 1234567,89
fr_FR.UTF-8: 1234567,89
he_IL.UTF-8: 1,234,567.00
hr_HR.UTF-8: 1234567,89
hu_HU.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
hy_AM.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
is_IS.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
it_CH.UTF-8: 1234567,89
it_IT.UTF-8: 1234567,89
ja_JP.UTF-8: 1,234,567.00
kk_KZ.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
ko_KR.UTF-8: 1,234,567.00
lt_LT.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
nl_BE.UTF-8: 1234567,89
nl_NL.UTF-8: 1234567,89
no_NO.UTF-8: 1.234.567,89
pl_PL.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
pt_BR.UTF-8: 1.234.567,89
pt_PT.UTF-8: 1234567,89
ro_RO.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
ru_RU.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
sk_SK.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
sl_SI.UTF-8: 1234567,89
sr_YU.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
sv_SE.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
tr_TR.UTF-8: 1234567,89
uk_UA.UTF-8: 1 234 567,89
zh_CN.UTF-8: 1,234,567.00
zh_HK.UTF-8: 1,234,567.00
zh_TW.UTF-8: 1,234,567.00
$
```

The input string uses a comma; when the radix character is `.`, it means that the `,89` is left in the input for further processing.

Your mileage will vary.  Let me know your operating system and C library if `scanf()` supports the grouping character in the input.

*Note that you're not supposed to process the output of `ls` because of possible spaces, newlines and assorted other 'gotcha' characters that can appear in file names.  However, I checked that it would be safe for me before using it.  YMMV!*

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that 1.000.000 is 1, you need to type 1000000

Answer (score 0):

You can read a line as a string, using the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Afterwards, you can convert it to a `long int` using the function [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), or to a `double` using the function [`strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof). However, the function `strtod` will interpret a `.` in the number as a [decimal point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Radix_point), not as [digit grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping). The function `strtol` will treat such a character as an invalid character, and will stop trying to match a number. You may be able to change the behavior of these functions to suit your needs by [changing the locale](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale), however, this is platform-specific functionality, which means it may work on one compiler, but not on another.

If `.` is supposed to represent digit grouping, and you want it to be accepted as input, then the most reliable solution would probably be to read one line of input using `fgets` and then discard the `.` digit group separators, before attempting to convert the string to a `long int` using `strtol`.

If, after converting the numbers to a `lont int`, you want the number to be printed in groups of 3 with a `.` separating character, then it would probably best to create your own function to do this.

Here is an example program which does everything described above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 100

void print_with_group_separation( long );

int main( void )
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    char line_without_separators[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    char *p, *q;

    //prompt user for input
    printf( "Please enter an integer: " );

    //attempt to read one line of input
    if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        printf( "input error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //attempt to find newline character
    if ( (p=strchr(line,'\n')) == NULL )
    {
        printf( "line was too long\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //remove newline character
    *p = '\0';

    //print back string to user
    printf( "You entered the string: %s\n", line );

    //copy line while discard group separating characters
    p = line;
    q = line_without_separators;
    do
    {
        if ( *p != '.' )
            *q++ = *p;

    } while ( *p++ != '\0' );

    //print string after removing separators
    printf( "String after removing separators: %s\n", line_without_separators );

    //attempt to convert string to "long int"
    long l = strtol( line_without_separators, &p, 10 );

    //verify that conversion was successful
    if ( p == line_without_separators )
    {
        printf( "unable to convert string to integer!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //print converted result
    printf( "The string was successfully converted to the following integer: %ld\n", l );

    //print the same number with group separation
    printf( "The same number with group separation: " );
    print_with_group_separation( l );
    printf( "\n" );
}

//NOTE: This function assumes that "num" is not negative. It won't
//attempt to create more than 4 groups of digits, because ISO C
//only requires "long int" to be able to represent
//numbers up to 2,147,483,647.
void print_with_group_separation( long num )
{
    long quotient;
    long remainder;
    bool has_printed = false;

    //calculate billions
    quotient  = num / 1000000000;
    remainder = num % 1000000000;

    //print billions
    if ( quotient != 0 )
    {
        printf( "%ld.", quotient );
        has_printed = true;
    }

    //calculate millions
    quotient  = remainder / 1000000;
    remainder = remainder % 1000000;

    //print millions
    if ( has_printed || quotient != 0 )
    {
        if ( has_printed )
            printf( "%03ld.", quotient );
        else
            printf( "%ld.", quotient );

        has_printed = true;
    }

    //calculate thousands
    quotient  = remainder / 1000;
    remainder = remainder % 1000;

    //print thousands
    if ( has_printed || quotient != 0 )
    {
        if ( has_printed )
            printf( "%03ld.", quotient );
        else
            printf( "%ld.", quotient );

        has_printed = true;
    }

    //print remainder
    if ( has_printed )
        printf( "%03ld", remainder );
    else
        printf( "%ld", remainder );
}
```

This program has the following output, using the input from the question:

```
Please enter an integer: 1.000.000
You entered the string: 1.000.000
String after removing separators: 1000000
The string was successfully converted to the following integer: 1000000
The same number with group separation: 1.000.000
```

This program also works with different input:

```
Please enter an integer: 324.112.532
You entered the string: 324.112.532
String after removing separators: 324112532
The string was successfully converted to the following integer: 324112532
The same number with group separation: 324.112.532
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have only 1 integer/float/double to have 2 dots. I recommend you to receive the input as a string and break it down into parts of integer/float/double then do your calculation or whatever then combine them together again into a string and output it. For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[15];
    //get input
   scanf("%s", string); //type in 1.000.000
   //"." indicate the break
   char * token = strtok(string, ".");
   char partOfNumber[3][15];
   int i = 0;
   while( token != NULL ) {
      //assign parts to string separately
      strcpy(partOfNumber[i],token);
      token = strtok(NULL, ".");
      i++;
   }
    //turn part into integer
    int number1 = atoi(partOfNumber[0]);
    int number2 = atoi(partOfNumber[1]);
    int number3 = atoi(partOfNumber[2]);
   //do calculation with the number or whatever...
   
   //now we combine them together again...
   return 0;
}
```

Do notice if you want it to assign 0 in the middle please use some loop/if-else statement to achieve.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).